# Identify the lambda responsible for the flow logs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm looking for a way to associate flow logs to the originating Lambda.
Since the new networking model for Lambdas' networking ([announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/)) it seems this isn't possible anymore (since multiple Lambdas use the same ENI).
Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! The ENIs are only shared between lambdas using the same security group (Since security group is attached to the ENI) and subnet.

A workaround would be configuring each lambda function with its own security group.

It might be a pain if you have a lot of lambdas connected to the VPC using the same security group, at least security groups are free. :) But watch out for [VPC limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html), there is a soft limit of 2500 security groups per region.

Comment: Thanks @Erico! I'm aware of these options but was hoping for a way to resolve the flow logs in setups I don't control. In addition, it has a bad impact on cold start so I'm not sure this work around is a recommended approach (unless you really need it).

Comment: No problem! Yes, I don't see a nice way around to be honest, but it's a great question for AWS support. 

Actually there is no direct impact on cold starts because the ENI is created during lambda creation and used on every execution, it's the main improvement of the change, the difference is that you'd have more ENIs, what can happen is if the lambda is not executed for a long time (weeks) as described on the post you referenced, AWS reclaims the ENI and then you could have a slow cold start.

Comment: We opened a ticket with AWS support and there aren't any better solutions at the moment