# Lambda IP address originating from subnet CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function residing in a VPC making a get request to a private API Gateway, so traffic is all internal to the VPC.
Note: I have created a [custom domain for the private API Gateway](https://georgemao.medium.com/enabling-private-apis-with-custom-domain-names-aws-api-gateway-df1b62b0ba7c)

Here is the configurations:

```
Lambda ENI IP address - 172.31.21.183
Lambda VPC CIDR - 172.31.0.0/16
Lambda Subnet CIDR - 172.31.16.0/20

Source IP address (as seen in APIGW access logs) - 172.31.128.48
```

Upon enabling API Gateway access logging, I see that request made from Lambda has the IP address `172.31.128.48` which is an IP that is outside the subnet CIDR configured with Lambda.

Seeking clarity into how this is possible?

Comment: How are you determining that the Lambda ENI has IP 172.31.21.183? For each subnet, Lambda creates a network interface for each unique set of security groups. Interesting that 172.31.128.48 is indeed not in 172.31.16.0/20.

Comment: Is 172.31.128.48 the IP address of the interface VPC endpoint you are using for the private API Gateway API?

Comment: >How are you determining that the Lambda ENI has IP 172.31.21.183?

- checked the function's ENI via [Lambda ENI finder tool](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-eni-find-delete), then went to EC2 -> Network interfaces and confirmed it has the IP `172.31.21.183`

- The IP addresses for the APIGW VPCE are `172.31.220.146, 172.31.162.88,172.31.30.223` so it's not that. 

Quite stumped on this one

Comment: Wonder if VPC Flow Logs would shine a light on what's going on (be aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791998/identify-the-lambda-responsible-for-the-flow-logs-in-aws)).